# cannot do a where clause with jooq DSL in Kotlin/Java

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I am trying to run a query of the following form with jooq in Kotlin:

```
val create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
val query: Query = create.select().from(DSL.table(tableName))
            .where(DSL.field("timestamp").between("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z").and("2021-11-05T00:00:00Z"))
            .orderBy(DSL.field("id").desc())
```

The code above gives me:

```
syntax error at or near \"and\
```

Also, looking at this query in the debugger, the `query.sql` renders as:

```
select * from data_table where timestamp between ? and ? order by id desc
```

I am not sure if the `?` indicates that it could not render the values to SQL or somehow they are some sort of placeholders..

Also, the code works without the `where` chain.

Additionally, on the Postgres command line I can run the following and the query executes:

```
select * from data_table where timestamp between '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' and '2021-11-05T00:00:00Z' order by id
```

Querying the datatypes on the schema, the `timestamp` column type is rendered as `timestamp without time zone`.

Before I had declared variables as:

```
val lowFilter = "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"
val highFilter = "2021-11-05T00:00:00Z"
```

and this did not work and it seems passing raw strings does not work either. I am very new to this, so I am pretty sure I am messing up the usage here.

**EDIT**
Following @nulldroid suggestion, did something like:

```
.where(DSL.field("starttime").between(DSL.timestamp("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")).and(DSL.timestamp("2021-11-05T00:00:00Z")))
```

and this resulted in:

```
Type class org.jooq.impl.Val is not supported in dialect POSTGRES"
```

Comment: just a wild guess, but maybe a data type issue? 
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/datetime-functions/timestamp-function/
Apart from that, is there any particular reason, why you are using DSL.field("xyz")? When you're using Kotlin, you can import data classes as is, using the jooq uppercase syntax to access fields.

Comment: @nulldroid So, I tried casting these to `DSL.timestamp` and got the error `"Not supported by dialect : Type class org.jooq.impl.Val is not supported in dialect POSTGRES"`

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I'm really not in the confidence space here, either. What is your data class called? Let's say it's called "Transaction", I believe you would import it and do something like: Transaction.TIMESTAMP.between...   https://blog.jooq.org/10-nice-examples-of-writing-sql-in-kotlin-with-jooq/

Comment: @dulldroid I appreciate any discussion! This would be a problem for me. I want to construct this on the fly, so the `where` filter columns are selected dynamically by the user. I will try some hard coded values for the moment to see if I can get it to work...

Comment: What version of `jooq` do you use? Can't reproduce - this code [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vltu4.png) on my machine with `org.jooq:jooq:3.15.4`

Comment: I am using `3.15.1`. Could I ask you if `query.sql` is also correct in your case? Would you mind posting the content of `query.sql`?

Comment: Also, in y db the timestamp type is shown as `timestamp without time zone`. Is it the same type in your postgres db?

Comment: Why aren't you using the [code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Not using the code generator:

I'm going to assume you have a good reason not to use the [code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/) for this particular query, the main reason usually being that your schema is dynamic.

So, the correct way to write your query is this:

```kotlin
create.select()
      .from(DSL.table(tableName))

      // Attach a DataType to your timestamp field, to let jOOQ know about this
      .where(DSL.field("timestamp", SQLDataType.OFFSETDATETIME)

          // Use bind values of a temporal type
          .between(OffsetDateTime.parse("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"))
          .and(OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-11-05T00:00:00Z")))
      .orderBy(DSL.field("id").desc())
```

Notice how I'm using actual temporal data types, not strings to compare dates and declare fields.

I'm assuming, from your question's UTC timestamps, that you're using `TIMESTAMPTZ`. Otherwise, if you're using `TIMESTAMP`, just replace `OffsetDateTime` by `LocalDateTime`...

#### Using the code generator

If using the code generator, which is *always* recommended if your schema isn't dynamic, you'd write almost the same thing as above, but type safe:

```kotlin
create.select()
      .from(MY_TABLE)

      // Attach a DataType to your timestamp field, to let jOOQ know about this
      .where(MY_TABLE.TIMESTAMP

          // Use bind values of a temporal type
          .between(OffsetDateTime.parse("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"))
          .and(OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-11-05T00:00:00Z")))
      .orderBy(MY_TABLE.ID.desc())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this as well as LocalDateTime before...Somehow my SQL query in the debugger always shows up as:

```
"sql_query":"select * from data_table where ts between cast(? as timestamp with timezone) and cast(? as timestamp with timezone) order by id desc fetch next 1000 rows only
```

I do not understand why the `?` and why the actual value does not get rendered...

Comment: Why not? Bind variables are good. But that's not the main question you've had here. I'll be happy to answer that one, too, if you ask a new question, specifically including whyt that's bothering you.

Comment: Ah ok, that is because of binding. Sorry I am super new to this, so still finding my feet. I will update the question soon.

Comment: I wish I can buy you a beer. That last comment was everything. I needed a `DSL.inline`!